# nginx неверно интерпретирует alias

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Имеется nginx 1.10.3 и задача положить phpmyadmin в подпапку.

конфиг нджинкса:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/site/;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                index  index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri = 404;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                }


        }

        location /myadm {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                alias /var/www/phpmyadmin;
                index  index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                }
        }
}
```

в итоге в логах видно что он пытается искать index.php не в /var/www/phpmyadmin а в /var/www/phpmyadmin/myadm. Я никак не возьму в толк в чем беда, ведь директива alias как раз и должна отрезать location, или нет?

Comment: добавь слешей: `location /myadm/ { alias /var/www/phpmyadmin/; ...}`

Comment: `FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/phpmyadmin//myadm/index.php (No such file or directory)"`
Т.е. все тоже самое.

Comment: тогда воспользуйся вот этим ответом https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378129/4496422

Answer (score 0):

В итоге придумал такой конфиг, вроде работает:

```
location ^~ /myadm {
        alias /var/www/phpmyadmin;
        index index.php index.html;

        location ~* \.php$ {

           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        }
}
```